# Sum the time in field type varchar

Tags: mysql, sum

i have a database with Id(int),name(varchar),Time(varchar)

the time is in this format (HH:MM)

and i want to sum the time for every Id

i tried this but it returns an error in Mysql :

```
SELECT Id,
SUM( 60 * CONVERT(int, LEFT( Time, 2)) + CONVERT(int, RIGHT(Time, 2)) ) AS 
TotalMinutes
FROM retards
GROUP BY Id;
```

can someone tell me what's wrong?

this is the error, it's a syntax error as it returns :

MySQL a répondu : Documentation

## 1064 - Erreur de syntaxe près de 'int, LEFT( total, 2)) + CONVERT(int, RIGHT(total, 2)) ) AS TotalMinutes

FROM re' à la ligne 2

Comment: Edit your question and show the full text of the error. It's kinda important since that will tell us what is wrong.

Comment: @SloanThrasher i edited the question

Comment: My french is a little rusty, but for clarity's sake it's worth noting that OP's table name is french for "delays". Just sayin.

Comment: Also, you should probably be storing that `Time` value as an integer so you can do math and sorting on it without having to convert it all the time.

Comment: @Sammitch yes it's delays, i alredy worked on this table so i can't change the type of time, that's why i converted to int and converted the hours to minutes .. but i don't know what's wrong

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert You've got the arguments backwards and you need to specify `SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED`, not `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't be better using of direct conversion?

```
TIME_TO_SEC(CONVERT(`Time`,time)) / 60 AS `TotalMinutes`
```

full query:

```
SELECT Id,
SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CONVERT(`Time`,time)) / 60) AS 
`TotalMinutes`
FROM retards
GROUP BY Id;
```